# UICollectionView Rotation incorrect layout after rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rotation

I have a UICollectionView which is exactly 7 cells wide, with no padding in between. I have done this by adding a flow layout with no interim or line spacing and calculating the width as follows:

```
public func collectionView(
    _ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
    layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, 
    sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath
) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(
        width: self.frame.width / CGFloat(7), 
        height: self.frame.height - headerHeight
    )
}
```

This works fantastically within my iPhone app

[image]

where rotation isn't enabled. On iPad, when in portrait mode this works fine.

[image]

When rotating, firstly the app doesn't redraw, I've attempted to invalidateLayout however this didn't solve the issue. I have to scroll down and I get the following layout

[image]

When I tap a cell it does however redraw, but with padding added pushing the 7th cell down onto another row.

[image]

I am looking to redraw the cells so all 7 fit on a single row when the app is either rotated or grown and shrunk in split view. How should I handle this correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this in your `UIViewController` class

It will adjust your layout automatically while you change device orientation.

```
override func viewWillLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewWillLayoutSubviews()
        
    guard let columnLayout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout else {
        return
    }
    columnLayout.invalidateLayout()
}
```

Comment: This worked on all iPad sizes except for the 11 inch iPad Pro but only when in full-screen mode. It resizes correctly when in slide over, and all other sizes while in split screen. The 11" is what I took the above screenshots with, it's adding padding between the cells which isn't happening on any other device. Any ideas?

Comment: @SonnieHiles what you have done in the collectionViewLayout method?

Comment: I am still using the same code as in the original question, returning the size of the cell as follows: `return CGSize(width: self.frame.width/CGFloat(7), height: self.frame.height - headerHeight)`.

Comment: Solved the issue on the iPad Pro 11". Needed to `floor()` the resulting value to round it down so that it fits within the screen dimensions and wasn't pushed down to the next row.